# Quotes on header of each page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, book-class

I have this question today: how can I store some quotes pre-hand in a csv file, say

```
"quote 1 statement",author 1,year
"quote 2 statement",author 2,year
...
"quote n statement,author n,year
```

and then add these quotes on headers of each page in my [math]{\LaTeX}[/math] document? I've seen this in many places, and wanted to add something like it in my document too. I've tried searching, but couldn't find a, say package or something that deals with it... Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: Following the notice from bot:

> Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am making this update:

Basically I want to add a quote on the top of each page of my document. (Different quote for each page). For this, I was hoping to store them in a csv file like above, then use the file to take the quotes, and print them on headers of the pages of my document, like

``Quote i statement''     --- *author i, year*

It doesn't have to be a csv file specifically. I just needed a solution in whatever shape reasonably possible...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz... Hi, I am not facing any error, so there is no debugging required... I am not sure where to begin with in this problem, so that is why I cannot provide an example test file. I needed guidance on ways this can be made possible — printing different quotes in headers of my documents' pages... one at a page.

Comment: A possible solution will depend on your class. Without knowing at least your basic setup, there is little sense in making guesses.

Comment: Ah... that makes sense. I use the `book` documentclass and the document will be compiled using LuaLaTeX. There's very heavy formatting in the whole document. It's actually a magazine... Terrible thing to make with LaTeX, but well... 

Comment: Oh... off topic, but can I just say, I LOVE your tikzduck package I just found out. Surely gonna use it a lot... I like ducks 

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ^^^

Comment: @n11 So happy to hear you like the ducks!

Comment: @n11 In the future, please add a short, but compilable test document to your questions. Writing stuff like `\documentclass` etc. over and over is really boring. If there already is a small test document, one can directly jump into working on a solution and can skip all these boring tasks.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\readlist*\mydata{{Quote A}, {Quote B}, {Quote C}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[c]{\mydata[\value{page}]}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great idea to use `listofitems`!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thank you!